# rsync in shell for loop

Tags: shell, for-loop, sh, rsync

I have this shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
PATHS=( a b c d )

for PATH in ${PATHS[@]}
do
  rsync -avziP /home/user/$PATH $SERVER:$server_folder -b --backup-dir=$backup_folder/backup_$date --delete --exclude=.* --log-file=$HOME/rsync.log
done
```

And I always get this error:

> rsync: command not found

What is driving me crazy is that if I delete the for loop, and just run the rsync command, the script works perfectly

Comment: By the way, you're using arrays (`${PATHS[@]}`), which is bash-only feature. You're better off with specifying something like `#!/bin/bash` in your shebang, or it will probably blow sooner or later - most Linux distributions tend to remove bash as default sh implementation, BSD/Macs never had bash as sh.

Comment: Best practice is to use lower-case variable names (`path`) for anything that isn't either an environment variable or a builtin; this avoids stomping on reserved names (like `PATH`) by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATH` is a reserved variable!

It is the variable specifying where to search tools (like `rsync`)

```
$ set | grep ^PATH=
PATH=/home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Use another variable name!

Avoid upper case in script variable names:

```
allPaths=( a b c d )
for onePath in "${allPaths[@]}"; do
    rsync -avziP "/home/user/$PATH" "$SERVER:$server_folder" -b \
        --backup-dir="$backup_folder/backup_$date" --delete --exclude=".*" \
        --log-file="$HOME/rsync.log"
done
```

And keep habit of enclosing your variable in double quotes when used as argument!